# docmosis - repeating row (or section) is not wrapping big text

Tags: docmosis

I try to integrate docmosis into my product, using the [docmosis-java](https://www.docmosis.com/resources/docmosis-java.html).

I’ve encountered an issue where there is a Java object that contains a member with huge text.

I have declared a repeating-row in my template (as I may have more than one instance from this type). In this case, the text (which is huge, contains many pages) appears partially in the report; only a single page is shown; it seems that instead of wrapping to the next page, to show the rest of the text, it is cut hence invisible in the report.

This is my template:

[image]

As mentioned, when “getBody()” return HUGE text, it is not visible in the report – only the first page of it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your template is using a table. If so, you should check that your table allows the rows to break across pages.  If this is disabled, it is likely to produce only partial results since you have said the row must be on a a single page.

Does that help?

Comment: yes indeed, that helps! had to go to the "table layout" --> "properties" (in Word) and tick there "allow rows to break across pages". Thanks!